# Finding the session id in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

How can I get the current session id in rails 3?

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
session[:session_id]
session['session_id']
session[:id]
session['id']
session.id
session.session_id
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
request.session_options[:id]
```

Comment: Well, that looks like a session_id to me :)

Comment: It's `session.id` in Rails 4.

Comment: It's change introduced in `rack`. More info at: https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/342

Comment: this useless in context of `#create`. because right after session create action new session ID would be persisted (to Redis in my case)
so this is UNSAFE method

Answer (score 8):

It also returns the session ID:

```
session[:session_id]
```

Comment: not if you are using session fixation protection by using `reset_session`

Answer (score 4):

[Rails 4.0](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionDispatch/Request/Session/id) onwards should be:

```
session.id
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to see data written in Session store for given session id from Rails console you can:

```
a = Rails.application.config.session_store.new(app, Rails.application.config.session_options)
a.class # => ActionDispatch::Session::RedisStore
a.get_session(ENV, '07319b2485be9ac4850664cd47cede38')


# or a.find_session(ENV, '07319b2485be9ac4850664cd47cede38')
```

`app` and`ENV` are set when you start rails console, don't need to set those

you can get the `session_id` via some a browser plugin dealing with cookies or  (cookie inspector, cookies manager, ...)

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it right now but as far as I know the session id variable changed from `'id'` to `'session_id'` on Rails 3, have you tried that one? Hope it works for you.

Comment: yeah..id variable changed from 'id' to 'session_id' on Rails 3. what do to do to access id of table?