# User authentication withRails 3 and Sencha 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am developing a simple application on Rails 3 using basic authentication. 
The application checks for a valid session on every request. How can I manage sessions using Sencha?  I tried to get the Rais Session to pass it as a param to sencha so it could send it back to the app.... but using *request.session[:id]*  or  *request.session[:session_id]* is not returning any value.

What would be the best way to approach this problem (keeping sessions)? I thought about creating my own session hash to use...

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from the beginning - not `request.session` but just `session`. Not `session[:id]` but  `request.session_options[:id]` (at least as described here: [Finding the session id in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824829/finding-the-session-id-in-rails-3) , works in rails4 as well).

How/Why do you want to manage session in Sencha? Sencha is fronend only, it has nothing to do. If yoy have properly configured session in `config/initializer/session_storage.rb`, then session_id should be passed in cookies on every request.

Comment: Yes, request.session_options[:id] works. I actually tried using it before but obviously was doing something wrong. I configured the session_storage.rb to use active record for my sessions, and the backend is working fine. I am not in charge of implementing the frontend, but as far as I understand, sencha doesn't keep cookies... the how will the request let the app know that there is a valid session in place? Thanks

Comment: Sencha have nothing to do with cookies - they are set by backend and send on every request automatically. So unless your doing something wrong, it should work out of the box. Please, open firebug in FF or inspector in home and take a look at request - you might want to download firecookie extension for firefox. To know if there's a valid session in place, you have to expose some extra info to sencha. Either add extra data do `<body>` (like `<body data-user-id="<%= current_user.id %>">`) or check via ajax after loading all scripts, etc.