# Rails 4.1.6 session ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How to get session id from a request object. 
Below code can be used in Rails 3 to get the session ID. But this doesn't seem to be working any more in **Rails 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.1.3**

```
request.session_options[:id]
```

Comment: Did you try `session.id`?

Comment: request.session.id always return the same value for one browser even on multiple request after closing or re-opening browser

Comment: According to others (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4824984/1015289) session.id appears to be correct and is also working for me. Perhaps the browser is keeping the history so the session may not clear until the session expires or history is manually cleared?

Answer (score 17):

```
session.id
```

This is the correct way to do it.