# Rails 4 session.id occasionally nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, session, heroku

I'm running a simple website on Heroku and I'm noticing something strange occurring when I'm running the app.  It appears that approximately 50-60% of my users are reporting a nil session_id when it gets logged in my database.

I'm using active_record_store for my session handler and Postgres as my db server. I've gotten similar results using the cookie_store, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. The only guess I have is that the first request a user makes, the id might not be populated yet.  The sessions table has the correct number of entries, but my tracking table does not.

**Example Code**

```
class CaptionController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @image = Image.order("RANDOM()").first
    Tracking.log(session.id, Tracking::VIEW_CAPTION_ON_IMAGE, @image.id)

  end
```

The code above results in 50% of the time, the session being nil in the table it logs to.

Comment: you see the same way you set `@image`? Where did you set/retrieve `session`?

Comment: According to the Rails 4 API, that's set by the Controller in advance.  I'm looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754239/rails-4-1-6-session-id for reference.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer, it looks like Rails is trying to be efficient by only creating a session if there is something to store. So accessing the session.id without storing something doesn't return consistent results.

You need to force the session to be created by storing something in it.

TLDR: Add this somewhere before you access the session ID.

```
session[:foo] = "bar"
```

**Source**: *http://www.gani.com.au/2013/08/force-session-creation-in-rails/*

Comment: This is not a bug but a dubious "feature" of the cookie session store in all versions of Rails. If a cookie does not exist (first time to site, or deleted cookies), then the session will be empty and thus the session ID will be nil.