# rails oAuth failing, session invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-oauth, omniauth

Rails application - I am trying to authenticate with google using oAuth using the gem omniauth. I have tried to follow the steps in the link [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/) but after signing in successfully with Google in the backend, application says that authentication has failed in the sessions_controller.rb.

I have narrowed down the error to this line in the *sessions_controller.rb*

```
session[:user_id] = @user.id
```

Now if I try to dump *session*, I get the following error

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 107ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
TypeError (can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0xa5a8b38>):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Why is the *session* invalid? How to rectify this?

Here is the sessions_controller.rb 'create' action code

```
begin
  @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
rescue
  logger.debug "Well, authentication failed?"
  flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you"
end
```

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting when it can't authenticate?

Comment: I get the flash warning --> flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you"

Comment: There's just not enough information to help you debug.  As a test,  I followed the tutorial - and everything worked swimmingly, so without seeing the rest of your code or a better set of errors (try adding `@user.errors.full_messages` to your debug statement) - there's not much help I can be to you.

Comment: This seems to be related to the session nil issue faced by others as well. For instance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772737/rails-4-session-id-occasionally-nil. I created a fresh app now again and don't see the same issue.