# Session tracking in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-cookies

Currently i am trying to implement session tracking in rails,
till now i was using

> "Rack::Session::__id_ "

so i was getting different session id's when i restart my rails server, but as i want to implement the tracking on user's session so i want a unique id whenever a new user starts his session.
i have tried a lot things but not getting anything as

```
session[:session_id]  
session['session_id']  
session[:id]  
session['id']  
session.id  
session.session_id
```

those are giving NIL values,

Comment: You need to use `session.id`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772737/rails-4-session-id-occasionally-nil

Comment: yeah i tried this its giving its session id but the session id is same for all the sessions , as i want to track different sessions so i need a unique id for every session.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
request.session_options[:id]
```

Comment: getting NIL for this also

Answer (score 0):

```
request.session.id
```

It's change introduced in rack. More info at: github.com/rack/rack/pull/342