# How to get current session id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Without user login hoe to to get current session id.
I want the current  session id  without user login to store on db

Any help is appreciated

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824829/finding-the-session-id-in-rails-3), it's: `session.id`

Comment: But you really should not store the session id in the database because of [session fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), which is a serious security threat. The common solution is to use a [guest user record](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record) if you want to associate something with the user without signup.