# Rails devise, find current_user by session_store key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, warden

We have a production system (main app) running on Rails with devise gem configured (using Redis session store)(session is enabled for all subdomain)

I need to build a custom authentication service for one of our subdomain based microservice. For each request, this microservice will be calling our main app with session id (the cookie value of rails session store key) (which is configured in config/initializers/session_store.rb).

So the question is, can I find the user just by session id? (Using Devise or Warden)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a method Devise's Authenticatable module adds to your resource called [`serialize_from_session`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L230).  You can pass in an expanded Warden session variable, which includes both the key and salt (`serialize_from_session` accepts both of those as parameters).  For example, if you are using Devise on a User model:

```
user = User.serialize_from_array(*session['warden.user.user.key'])
```

The `session['warden.user.user.key']` variable is an array of the record ID (as an array) and a salt.  It would look something like `[[1], "$2f$23$2DIUF7Vr.J5sbfGwHTew"]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

For this to work, I need a session object. But I don't have a session object (Assum inside rails console). I only have session id. So how can I find this warden info from Redis ?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are handling session?  "calling our main app with the cookie value of rails session store key".  My thought was you could get the session data by querying the Redis session store for the key in the cookie

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question.

Now I got the solution by merging your answer with https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319202/1866804 

Thanks for the help @xavier